# Why am I getting NoSuchMethodError in my Java webapp?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have set up my spring-mvc webapp according to tutorials I have read.

Here is my controller class:

```
package hellowebapp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Here is my servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="hellowebapp"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<web-app>    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWebapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWebapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my hello.jsp file:

```
<%@ page contentType = "text/html; charset = UTF-8" %>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h2>${message}</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hellowebapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWebapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>HelloWebapp</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The directory structure shows in a list of files and paths:

1. src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp
2. src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/HelloWebapp-servlet.xml
3. src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
4. src/main/java/hellowebapp/HelloController.java
5. pom.xml

I can package my webapp with "mvn clean package" and run it with "mvn jetty:run". When I point my web browser to http://localhost:8080/HelloWebapp/hello, I get this error message:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

'int javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()'
RequestURI=/HelloWebapp/hello

Caused by:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1023)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Powered by Jetty://
```

Why am I getting this error message? How can I make the webapp work as intended?

Answer (score 2):

Jetty 6.x uses Servlet 2.5 and the `int javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()` is added in Servlet 3.x. Spring framework 5.x uses Servlet 3.x so you must use compatible jetty version.

Update the `maven-jetty-plugin` maven plugin to at least 8.x or better 9.x if you are using Java 8 and if you are using Java 11 or later then update to 10.x.

Refs:

1. https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.php#version-table
2. https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/10/feedback-welcome-spring-5-system-requirements

Answer (score 2):

@ktm5124. In normal @controller is required for response serialization in the method level so you could include the below sample.

```
@GetMapping("/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Book getBook(@PathVariable int id) {
    return findBookById(id);
}
```

Comment: This is only required when you want a JSON response in a Rest endpoint. OP is using JSP views.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below dependency in pom.xml because mentioned method not supported in older versions.

javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus() was added in Servlet 3.0

Add the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is not necessary unless the `javax.servlet` classes are used in the code (not in the dependencies) so the code will be compiled. Also, if the `javax.servlet-api` dependency is added  it must be in `provided` scope.